# Can I use useState in useRef variable or javascript variable like let?

Tags: reactjs, use-state, use-ref

Can I use useState like this below code?

```
const testRef = useRef({ test: useState("11" });
```

or

```
const testObj = {
    test: useState("HI");
}
```

or

```
let testRef = useRef(useState("HI"));
```

Comment: You can use it anywhere the statement is evaluated unconditionally, so yes to all the above. But why would you want to do this?

Comment: Yes you can, but i don't see the point

Comment: @Patrick Roberts I'm just curious about it. Is there any performance problem with that?

Comment: It's just unclear what, if anything, you're trying to accomplish. Without that there's nothing to be gained by answering this.